# Using python identify text within a polygon stored in a text file

Tags: python, text

Suppose I have text:

```py
+------------------+
|                  |
|     (txta)       |
|                  |
|     A   B   C    |
+------------------+
|                  |
|     (txtb)       |
|                  |
|     B       B    |
+------------------+
```

I need to read this text file and output the below . Idea is to identify the "rectangle's" text and then identify how many As Bs and Cs are in the rectangle so for the above text input the output would read below as

```
txta A 1 B 1 C 1  
txtb A 0 B 2 C 0
```

Output can be in any format (list/dictionary/etc.) as long as the name in the brackets (txta and txtb in this case) are identified in the rectangle and then the number of As Bs Cs are counted and reported.

I don't know what to try.

Comment: Hi, and welcome! Have a read of this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. People usually ask about what you've tried so far, if anything, or at least see that you've thought a bit about the problem. Also, be very specific about the input and output. For example, are you reading a text file here, or is the input an image? If it's a text file, just provide the text, not an image. Assuming you have actual text to work with, you're going to find [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) handy.

Comment: Much appriciated to guide a first time poster; this is a text file and I am editing the question to ensure the file is there. I will edit the question for the output as well it just needs to be a string. I have not been able to even begin solving because I dont know how to begin.

Comment: so i have added the text file to git and made it public access. link takes one to the file.

Comment: does the content change or is it always A and B ?

Comment: @NaveshKumar Links or images of code, error messages or necessary data/information are off-topic. They should be in the question itself, formatted in code blocks.

Comment: 2nd question: how should your output look like ? should it just `print` out what you suggested in your question or does it need to be a `list/dataframe/dict` ?

Comment: Unable to show my immense appriciation here for the first question I posted and the edits that came so quickly. @Rabinzel  Answer 1 the text file is static and Answer 2 no specified output format requirement other than we need to identify txta is in the first "rectangle" and txtb is in the second "rectangle" and the count of As and Bs in these "rectangles" repectively ; but a list with the format {'shape_label_a' : {'a_count': 'count_of_a', 'b_count':'count_of_b'} , 'shape_label_b' : {'a_count': 'count_of_a', 'b_count':'count_of_b'}} can be used as a direction of travel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) is one way to attack this kind of thing, but you know what they say about regex:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.” 
> Now they have two problems.

Now, I'm no regex guru and of course there are always lots of ways to do things. Depending on what the rest of your data looks like, this might break, but if `text` is that string you shared, then this works:

```py
import re
from collections import Counter

with open('path/to/file.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()

data = {}
for t in filter(None, text.split('+------------------+')):
    match = re.search(r"\((\w+?)\)", t)
    key, = match.groups()
    match = re.findall(r"(?:\s(\w))+?", t)
    data[key] = Counter(match)
```

After this, `data` looks like

```py
{'txta': Counter({'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 1}), 'txtb': Counter({'B': 2})}
```

You should be able to dig what you need out of there, e.g.

```py
for record, counter in data.items():
    counts = [f"{a} {counter.get(a, 0)}" for a in 'ABC']
    print(record, ' '.join(counts))
```

produces:

```
txta A 1 B 1 C 1
txtb A 0 B 2 C 0
```

Don't worry about those `Counter` things, they are essentially just dictionaries. And if you think the regex looks weird, yeah, it always looks like that. Some people like sites [like this](https://regex101.com/) to help figure things out.

Comment: how did you import the textfile ? or did you just put the whole file as a string to `text`?

Comment: @Rabinzel Good point, I added a way to get the text.

Comment: @kwinkunks : Many thanks for this guidance and direction of travel.  This is massively helpful!. I have also made some changes to the question based on the edit on the text file that now includes a "C" in the first "rectangle". Kindly do let me know if the above solution still stands. (PS : you are a guru indeed!)

Comment: Indeed, it will still work with one small change; I updated it.

Comment: @kwinkunks : it did and I have accepted but given my current low reputation points not too sure it will reflect or not. Many thanks!